# How to clear browser cache using java

Tags: java, guice-servlet

I have a problem in sessions. When ever I  logout the session is
ended but then when the browsers back button is pressed I am getting the previous page. I am using jsp servlet technology and my code for logout is given below

```
                    request.getSession().invalidate();
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
```

can anybody tell me where is the problem and what will be the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the cache headers only on the logout page?  If so, you need to put those on each page since the page you were coming from does not have them and will be cached.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    history.forward();
 </script>
```

Add this javascript to the page before that logout Page and call. 
Add below code on  tag

```
onLoad="if (location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) location.replace(location.href+'?reload')"
```

It will solve your back button issue.

Comment: I'd already use this, but i didn't work.

Comment: you need to refresh page to take effect. Note that generally the session truly ends only when the browser window closes.

Comment: After refresing the page also it doesn't work

Comment: Try to remove one value for now using session.removeValue() method. by passing the string identifier of the value you need to remove . try n let me know

Comment: can u kindly give me the complete code?

Comment: Thank u sir, it works. But one problem is there. If I run this on the browser then i doesn't work.

Comment: In Mozila it doesn't work, but in other browser it works. Thank u sir.

Comment: for that problem, you need to remove session values. Do it by removeAttribute() method of session

Answer (score 0):

Wirte your code as below,

```
     //...
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //Forces caches to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
     response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
     response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 backward compatibility

     //can check userId or something likes this.In this sample, i checked with userName.
     String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("User");
     if (null == userName) {
         request.setAttribute("Error", "Session has ended.  Please login.");
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
         rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```